# deparse(substitute()) with lapply

Tags: r, lapply, substitution

I want to give labels to data frames using a combination of a small function in combination with lapply()

I have the following code:

```
df1 <- data.frame(c(1,2,3), c(3,4,5))
df2 <- data.frame(c(6,7,8), c(9,10,11))

f.generate.name <- function(x) {
  x$name <- deparse(substitute(x))
  return(x)
  }

my_list <- list(df1, df2) 


# This works fine.
f.generate.name(df1)

# This does not work.
lapply(my_list, f.generate.name)
```

which produces the following output

```
[[1]]
  c.1..2..3. c.3..4..5.   name
1          1          3 X[[i]]
2          2          4 X[[i]]
3          3          5 X[[i]]

[[2]]
  c.6..7..8. c.9..10..11.   name
1          6            9 X[[i]]
2          7           10 X[[i]]
3          8           11 X[[i]]
```

What I want instead is:

```
[[1]]
  c.1..2..3. c.3..4..5.   name
1          1          3 df1
2          2          4 df1
3          3          5 df1

[[2]]
  c.6..7..8. c.9..10..11.   name
1          6            9 df2
2          7           10 df2
3          8           11 df2
```

What is the best way of dong this without using loops? How can I tweak the lapply() function or the function that I created in order to achieve the desired result?

Comment: the problem is that you create `my_list` with _copies_ of `df1` and `df2`, and those copies that are inside `my_list` are not called `df1` and `df2`. So where would the names `df1` and `df2` come from in a function that only takes `my_list` as an argument? It would be easy to do if you did `my_list <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2) `, but with an unnamed list, you are asking names to be extracted that just don't exist in the object you are passing.

Comment: @AllanCameron Fair enough. However, changing to `my_list <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2)` produces the same output.

Comment: of course, but there are then other ways around, like `lapply(names(my_list), function(x) {my_list[[x]]$name <- x; my_list[[x]];})`

Comment: Did you find any of the proposed solutions helpful? If so, please mark them as accepted that the community is aware of it. Otherwise, please explain what is missing. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

#### Base R

`lapply()` cannot iterate over more than one argument. You can use `mapply()` or its wrapper `Map()` in this case that always returns a list.

```
Map(f = function(x, y){
    x$name <- y
    x }, 
  my_list, 
  names(my_list))
$df1
  c.1..2..3. c.3..4..5. name
1          1          3  df1
2          2          4  df1
3          3          5  df1

$df2
  c.6..7..8. c.9..10..11. name
1          6            9  df2
2          7           10  df2
3          8           11  df2
```

### Tidyverse

In case you are open to a `purrr` solution, you can use `imap()`. It makes the names of the object conveniently available. There is no need to write a function then:

```
my_list <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2) 

imap(my_list, ~{
  .x$name <- .y
  .x
  })
$df1
  c.1..2..3. c.3..4..5. name
1          1          3  df1
2          2          4  df1
3          3          5  df1

$df2
  c.6..7..8. c.9..10..11. name
1          6            9  df2
2          7           10  df2
3          8           11  df2
```

Answer (score 0):

Really the question is where do the names come from?  An unnamed list like `my_list` in the question has lost the `df1` and `df2` names as we can see by looking at its internals:

```
dput(my_list)  # no df1 or df2 seen
## list(structure(list(c.1..2..3. = c(1, 2, 3), c.3..4..5. = c(3, 
## 4, 5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)), structure(list(
##     c.6..7..8. = c(6, 7, 8), c.9..10..11. = c(9, 10, 11)), class = 
## "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
## -3L)))
```

Thus either we need to create a named list in the first place or else provide a vector of names.  We show both using only base R.

### Named list

First create a named list of the data frames and then use Map as shown:

```
L <- mget(ls("^df"))  # create named list
Map(data.frame, L, name = names(L))
```

### Unnamed list

Alternately if all you have is an unnamed list then we can Map over that and a vector of names:

```
my_list <- list(df1, df2) # unnamed list as in question
Map(data.frame, my_list, name = c("df1", "df2"))
```

### Pass individual data frames

Yet another approach is to pass the individual data frames instead of a list.  Because we have not destroyed the original names by creating an unnamed list we can still retrieve them.  On R 4.0 and later `deparse1` could optionally be used in place of `deparse` in the code.

```
add_names <- function(...) {
  mc <- match.call()
  Map(data.frame, list(...), names = sapply(mc[-1], deparse))
}

add_names(df1, df2)
```